# CSS Program where I had issue in width of one div

Tags: css

Here, I am having a road and stripes where there are cars each side. I have that inside div and when I apply it, the div is not having full width. I am finding solution for it but it's not working.

```
 <div class="road">
            <div id="car-one" class="car-one">
                <div class="upper-body"></div>
                <div class="square-car"></div>
                <div class="wheels" id="tire-one"></div>
                <div class="wheels" id="tire-two"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="road-strips">
                <div class="stripe"></div>
                <div class="stripe"></div>
                <div class="stripe"></div>
                <div class="stripe"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="car-two">
                <div class="upper-body-two"></div>
                <div class="square-car-two"></div>
                <div class="wheels-two" id="tire-one2"></div>
                <div class="wheels-two" id="tire-two2"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.road {
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 18.5em;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that your problem is not the width of `.road` div, but the width of the parent div.

The width of the parent div affects the children elements. So when you write in `css` like:

```
.road {
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 100%;
```

This `100%` means the same width as the parent's width.

You can analyze your self, you can open the dev inspector panel by pressing `F12` in your browser or right click the page to open the context menu and press `inspect`.

After that, press `Ctrl+Shift+C` and hover on any elements you want. Then you will be able to see the rectangular size of elements.

In conclusion, it's all the `css`'s basics. The `css` stands for `Cascading Style Sheets`. In other words, the style is being applying in hirearchy.

You can see more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not set the width and height for the nested div and also the div content is empty so if you give height and width and any content inside the content you will see .road div having full width

```
CSS

    .road {
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-top: 18.5em; */
    height: 650px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.car-one{
   height:33.33%;
   background-color: orange;
}
.road-strips{
   height:33.33%;
   background-color: yellow;
}

.car-two{
  height:33.33%;
   background-color: green;
}
```